# Is There an Expedient Way to Color-Fill a Curve in R?

Tags: r, plot, fill

I am familiar with `polygon` and `ggplot2`, but I like working with basic `plot`.

I want to fill in the curve called by the command:

`curve(dnorm(x, 0.5, 0.22), xlim=c(-0.5, 1.5))`

[image]

When in the past I have used `polygon` I defined the end points based on prior calculations of `x` along the lines of `x <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, len = 100)`, for example, and `y <- dnorm(x, 0.5, 0.22)`. Next, the limits are defined within `polygon`, the color selected, et voilà... in less than a fortnight, there is color...

OK, not exactly fast, but in this particular case, I haven't even explicitly defined `x` and `y` outside `curve`, which makes the whole process even more cumbersome. It's almost like starting afresh.

Is there any way of doing it fast, perhaps with something like `fill`, `col` or other plotting parameters within `curve`?

Comment: If you are no planning to use `polygon` from scratch, then I think you would need to modify the code for `curve`.

Comment: Is there an alternative without resorting to ggplot2? I really don't like its aesthetics... and I'm not referring to the use of the word in ggplot2.

Comment: I certainly said nothing about using ggplot methods. The answer below was what I was anticipating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually modify the `curve` function relatively easily. The only changes I've made are:

1) Add a `fill` parameter defaulting to "red"

2) Add a `polygon` plot at the end of the function (marked with a comment)

Here's the function in action. See below for the function code.

```
my_curve(dnorm(x, 0.5, 0.22), xlim=c(-0.5, 1.5), fill="green")
```

[image]

I'm not sure that this is any more expedient that just doing:

```
x=seq(-0.5,1.5,0.01)
plot(x, dnorm(x,0.5,0.22), xlim=c(-0.5,1.5), type="l")
polygon(x, dnorm(x,0.5,0.22), col="green")
```

But if you're going to be using it a lot, you can source `my_curve` in your scripts or create a package with the new version of `curve` that masks the base version. You could also make the fill optional and perhaps add a feature that allows partial filling.

If you're not wild about the ggplot2 defaults, you can also get rid of them, while still keeping the benefits of ggplot's grammar:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x=seq(-0.5,1.5,0.01), y=dnorm(x,0.5,0.22))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_area(colour="black", fill="red") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

Here's the modified `curve` function:

```
my_curve = function (expr, from = NULL, to = NULL, n = 101, add = FALSE, 
                     type = "l", xname = "x", xlab = xname, ylab = NULL, log = NULL, 
                     xlim = NULL, fill="red", ...) 
{
  sexpr <- substitute(expr)
  if (is.name(sexpr)) {
    expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name(xname))
  }
  else {
    if (!((is.call(sexpr) || is.expression(sexpr)) && xname %in% 
          all.vars(sexpr))) 
      stop(gettextf("'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing '%s'", 
                    xname), domain = NA)
    expr <- sexpr
  }
  if (dev.cur() == 1L && !identical(add, FALSE)) {
    warning("'add' will be ignored as there is no existing plot")
    add <- FALSE
  }
  addF <- identical(add, FALSE)
  if (is.null(ylab)) 
    ylab <- deparse(expr)
  if (is.null(from) || is.null(to)) {
    xl <- if (!is.null(xlim)) 
      xlim
    else if (!addF) {
      pu <- par("usr")[1L:2L]
      if (par("xaxs") == "r") 
        pu <- extendrange(pu, f = -1/27)
      if (par("xlog")) 
        10^pu
      else pu
    }
    else c(0, 1)
    if (is.null(from)) 
      from <- xl[1L]
    if (is.null(to)) 
      to <- xl[2L]
  }
  lg <- if (length(log)) 
    log
  else if (!addF && par("xlog")) 
    "x"
  else ""
  if (length(lg) == 0) 
    lg <- ""
  if (grepl("x", lg, fixed = TRUE)) {
    if (from <= 0 || to <= 0) 
      stop("'from' and 'to' must be > 0 with log=\"x\"")
    x <- exp(seq.int(log(from), log(to), length.out = n))
  }
  else x <- seq.int(from, to, length.out = n)
  ll <- list(x = x)
  names(ll) <- xname
  y <- eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = parent.frame())
  if (length(y) != length(x)) 
    stop("'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'")
  if (isTRUE(add)) 
    lines(x = x, y = y, type = type, ...)
  else plot(x = x, y = y, type = type, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
            xlim = xlim, log = lg, ...)
       polygon(x,y, col=fill)  # Add filled area under curve
  invisible(list(x = x, y = y))
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!